# How to remove digit () using regex in php?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
Acer phones (36)
Yezz phones (13)
Nokia phones (371)
Apple (1)
```

How to remove (digit) in this text
I am using `preg_replace("^\(d\)$", "", $name[$i]);` // With `$name[$i] is Acer phones (36), Yezz phones (13)...`

Comment: `\d+`, not just `d`

Answer (score 2):

Use this example, which is a small adaptation from your attempt:

```
$a = "Acer phones (36)";
$a = preg_replace("#\(\d+\)$#", "", $a);
```

the # are the pattern delimiters (required by PHP, you can pick almost any character you want)

the ^ has been removed, because you don't need to look from the exact start of the string, but $ has been kept because the (NN) is at the end of the string

"d" has been replaced by `\d+` (remember to always escape special regex character, you forgot the escape in your example

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
preg_replace("/\(\d+?\)$/", "", $name[$i]);
```